# Read a specific node once from a Firebase Database using NativeScript

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How can I read the value of a node in a Firebase Database using Eddy Verbruggen's [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) plugin?

I would like to read the contents of the path:

```
/players/{player_id}
```

Is there something similar to FIRDatabaseRef.observeSingleEvent() (in the iOS SDK) or firebase.database().once() (in the js SDK)?

In the nativescript-plugin-firebase plugin I tried using firebase.addValueEventListener(), however it receives a callback as a parameter and I would really like a method which returned a Promise with the read value instead. Also I would need to manually remove the observer after performing the read.

Using firebase.query() also doesn't seem quite right, because I would need to set filter, range and query for reading a single value in a specific path. There surely must exist a better way!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using firebase.query() with singleEvent = true. For this I created a function called once():

```
once(path, key) {
    return firebase.query(
      ()=>{},
      path,
      {
        singleEvent: true,
        orderBy: {
          type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.KEY
        },
        ranges: [{
          type: firebase.QueryRangeType.EQUAL_TO,
          value: key
        }],
        limit: {
          type: firebase.QueryLimitType.FIRST,
          value: 1
        }
      })
      .then(
        queryResult => {
          // A query result contains a dictionary containing all objects that matched the query criteria. As we are interested on obtaining a single object, we can assume that dictionary will have only a single element.
          // 
          let queryValue = queryResult.value;
          let keys = Object.keys(queryValue); 
          if (keys.length > 0) {
            let key = keys[0]
            let value = queryValue[key];
            return Promise.resolve(value);
          } else {
            return Promise.resolve(null);
          }
        }
      )
  }
```

That can be used like this:

```
once("/players", userId).then(userData => {console.log(userData)})
```

I'm not sure I like this approach very much. It seems that using query to access a specific node might be inneficient. I am still looking for a better solution. Thanks.